Azure LB Dynamic Backend-Pool isn't enabled when implementing CCM (Cloud Controller manager)
I am using kubernetes's out of tree cloud controller manager to link the kubernetes load balancer service to the azure's load balancers creation, I tried installing the ccm with both helm and manifests, in both cases, my azure lb's backend pool didn't  add my nodes to its pool.
At first I had this problem with HELM. you can read more upon it on my github issue . Now that i followed the ccm's out of tree example on github . My issue persists, this is a preview of my YAML file that has all my config and is similar to the github's example
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cloud-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    component: cloud-controller-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: control-plane
      component: cloud-controller-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: control-plane
        component: cloud-controller-manager
    spec:
      priorityClassName: system-node-critical
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: cloud-controller-manager
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
      tolerations:
      - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: "node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized"
        value: "true"
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
        operator: "Exists"
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: cloud-controller-manager
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/azure-cloud-controller-manager:v1.30.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - "cloud-controller-manager"
        args:
        - "--allocate-node-cidrs=true"       
        - "--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json" 
        - "--cloud-config-key=azure-cloud-config"
        - "--cloud-config-secret-namespace=kube-system"
        - "--enable-dynamic-reloading"
        - "--cloud-provider=azure"
        - "--cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16"
        - "--cluster-name=kubernetes"
        - "--controllers=*,-cloud-node"
        - "--configure-cloud-routes=true"
        - "--leader-elect=true"
        - "--route-reconciliation-period=10s"
        - "--v=4"
        - "--secure-port=10267"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 2Gi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10267
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cloud-config
          mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
          readOnly: true
        - name: etc-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/ssl
          readOnly: true
        - name: msi
          mountPath: /var/lib/waagent/ManagedIdentity-Settings
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: cloud-config
        secret:
          secretName: azure-cloud-config
      - name: etc-ssl
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/ssl
      - name: msi
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/waagent/ManagedIdentity-Settings

Kindly tell me if my flags are missing a config or such thing.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-cloud-config
  namespace: kube-system
type: Opaque
stringData:
  azure.json: |
    {
      "cloud": "AzurePublicCloud",
      "tenantId": "xxxx",
      "subscriptionId": "xxxx",
      "aadClientId": "xxxxx",
      "aadClientSecret": "xxxxxx",
      "resourceGroup": "xxxx",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "vmType": "Standard_A2_v2",
      "subnetName": "k8s-cluster-subnet",
      "securityGroupName": "k8s-cluster-network-security-group",
      "vnetName": "k8s-cluster-virtual-network",
      "vnetResourceGroup": "xxx",
      "routeTableName": "table",
      "cloudProviderBackoff": true,
      "cloudProviderBackoffRetries": 6,
      "cloudProviderBackoffExponent": 1.5,
      "cloudProviderBackoffDuration": 5,
      "cloudProviderBackoffJitter": 1,
      "cloudProviderRatelimit": true,
      "cloudProviderRateLimitQPS": 6,
      "cloudProviderRateLimitBucket": 20,
      "useManagedIdentityExtension": false,
      "userAssignedIdentityID": "",
      "useInstanceMetadata": true,
      "loadBalancerSku": "standard",
      "excludeMasterFromStandardLB": false,
      "maximumLoadBalancerRuleCount": 250,
      "tags": "a=b,c=d"
    }

I later add  - --cloud-provider=external to /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
and apply this command to label my master node
kubectl label nodes k8s-cluster-vm1 node-role.kubernetes.io/master=""
I wonder if the issue was with my azure secret or if I need to specify the azure config's path to /manifests/azure.json not delete it. The load balancer gets created and automatically with it the routing table (because I didn't create one) as well as its own public IP. But the backend pool just won't add the nodes.
